# Timestamp + Numeric hours in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, timestamp

In my Input tables I am trying to add hours (NUMERIC) to a timestamp

```
time_of_Day
2020-10-01 22:15:00
2020-11-01 15:04:00

hours_to_add
3
4

Expected result
2020-10-02 01:15:00
2020-11-01 19:04:00
```

I tried the following method but I get an error: invalid input syntax for type interval: "hours_to_add"

```
SELECT 
time_of_Day+ interval 'hours_to_add' hour 
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select time_of_Day + hours_to_add/24 from your_table;
```

This produces a result of `date` datatype.

If you wanted interval arithmetics (and have a result of `timestamp` datatype):

```
select time_of_day + hours_to_add * interval '1' hour from your_table
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a82c666e529d4b2d7858a9995787c9a)**:

```
with t as (
    select timestamp '2020-10-01 22:15:00' time_of_Day , 3 hours_to_add from dual
    union all select timestamp '2020-11-01 15:04:00', 4 from dual
)
select 
    t.*,
    time_of_day + hours_to_add/24 as_date, 
    time_of_day + hours_to_add * interval '1' hour as_timestamp
from t
```

```
TIME_OF_DAY         | HOURS_TO_ADD | AS_DATE             | AS_TIMESTAMP       
:------------------ | -----------: | :------------------ | :------------------
2020-10-01 22:15:00 |            3 | 2020-10-02 01:15:00 | 2020-10-02 01:15:00
2020-11-01 15:04:00 |            4 | 2020-11-01 19:04:00 | 2020-11-01 19:04:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple the value with a fixed interval:

```
select time_of_day + interval '1' hour * hours_to_add
from the_table;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cc2777704ccc9d2d2646cfc76ee6ca7)

Comment: I tried this and the result is exactly same as the input

Comment: @bp123: this does exactly what you want: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cc2777704ccc9d2d2646cfc76ee6ca7

Answer (score 1):

The **TIMESTAMP** datatype is an extension of the **DATE** datatype. It stores year, month, day, hour, minute, and second values. It also stores **fractional seconds**, which are not stored by the DATE datatype.

So, if you don't want to display the fractional seconds, then use proper format mask using TO_CHAR to display what you want.

Here is a working demo:

```
with your_table as
(
  select timestamp '2020-10-01 22:15:00' time_of_Day , 3 hrs from dual
  union all 
  select timestamp '2020-11-01 15:04:00', 4 from dual
)
select time_of_day, 
       to_char(time_of_day + interval '1' hour * hrs, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') new_time 
from your_table;

TIME_OF_DAY                    NEW_TIME           
------------------------------ -------------------
01-10-20 10:15:00.000000000 PM 2020-10-02 01:15:00
01-11-20 3:04:00.000000000 PM  2020-11-01 19:04:00
```

The timestamp will still have the fractional seconds stored as `02-10-20 1:15:00.000000000 AM`.